# JavaFX Password field not working

Tags: passwords, javafx, plaintext

In scene builder I have a password field with the fx:id passwordBox and in the corresponding controller class I have

@FXML private static PasswordField passwordBox = new PasswordField();

I ALSO TRIED

@FXML private static PasswordField passwordBox;

When I run the program the letters in the password field are plain text. The same thing happens when I preview the window in scene builder.  The password field is a PasswordField so I didn't mistake it for a TextField.

What can I do?

Edit:
FXML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="mainAnchor" opacity="1.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="408.0000999999975" styleClass="back" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="application.MainController">
  <!-- TODO Add Nodes -->
  <children>
    <Label fx:id="serverIPLbl" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="28.0" prefWidth="175.0" text="Server IP">
      <font>
        <Font name="Segoe UI" size="12.0" fx:id="x1" />
      </font>
    </Label>
    <TextField fx:id="serverIPBox" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="50.0" prefWidth="175.0" />
    <Label fx:id="portLbl" font="$x1" layoutX="215.0" layoutY="28.0" prefWidth="175.0" text="Port" />
    <TextField fx:id="portBox" layoutX="215.0" layoutY="50.0" prefWidth="175.0" />
    <Label fx:id="passwordLbl" font="$x1" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="81.0" prefWidth="175.0" text="Server Password" />
    <ImageView fx:id="settingsButton" fitHeight="23.0" fitWidth="23.0" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="137.0" onMouseClicked="#settingsClicked" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
      <image>
        <Image url="@../images/gear.png" />
      </image>
    </ImageView>
    <Button id="startServer" fx:id="connectButton" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="167.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#connectClicked" prefHeight="22.0" prefWidth="376.0" text="Connect" />
    <Label fx:id="usernameLbl" font="$x1" layoutX="215.0" layoutY="81.0" prefWidth="175.0" text="Username" />
    <TextField id="serverIPBox" fx:id="usernameBox" layoutX="215.0" layoutY="103.0" prefWidth="175.0" promptText="a-z A-Z 0-9 _ - chars allowed" />
    <ImageView id="favoriteButton" fx:id="favoritesButton" fitHeight="23.0" fitWidth="23.0" layoutX="55.0" layoutY="137.0" onMouseClicked="#favoritesClicked" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
      <image>
        <Image url="@../images/favorite.png" />
      </image>
    </ImageView>
    <PasswordField fx:id="passwordBox" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="103.0" prefWidth="175.0" promptText="Optional" />
  </children>
  <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@style.css" />
  </stylesheets>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Can you post your fxml file?

Answer (score 2):

**Issues with your code**

`@FXML` is an injection annotation for controller instances, you shouldn't use it in conjunction with `static` members or members which you initialize using the `new` keyword.

Instead the definition in your controller should be:

```
@FXML private PasswordField passwordBox;
```

**Additional considerations which may or may not apply in your case**

- Controller instances should always be created through an new FXMLLoader().load(...) call (not via a `new` keyword on the controller itself, unless you subsequently use [loader.setController()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setController%28java.lang.Object%29)).
- The fxml file must specify an  name for your password field which matches the name in your controller (in your case this name is `passwordBox`).

**Example**

*GatewayApplication.java*

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class GatewayApplication extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("passport.fxml"));
        AnchorPane layout = loader.load();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

*MainController.java*

Generated by [SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html) `View | Show Sample Skeleton`.

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;


public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private Button connectButton;

    @FXML
    private ImageView favoritesButton;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane mainAnchor;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField passwordBox;

    @FXML
    private Label passwordLbl;

    @FXML
    private TextField portBox;

    @FXML
    private Label portLbl;

    @FXML
    private TextField serverIPBox;

    @FXML
    private Label serverIPLbl;

    @FXML
    private ImageView settingsButton;

    @FXML
    private TextField usernameBox;

    @FXML
    private Label usernameLbl;


    @FXML
    void connectClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("password = " + passwordBox.getText());
    }

    @FXML
    void favoritesClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    }

    @FXML
    void settingsClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        assert connectButton != null : "fx:id=\"connectButton\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'passport.fxml'.";
        assert favoritesButton != null : "fx:id=\"favoritesButton\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'passport.fxml'.";
        assert mainAnchor != null : "fx:id=\"mainAnchor\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'passport.fxml'.";
        assert passwordBox != null : "fx:id=\"passwordBox\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'passport.fxml'.";
        assert passwordLbl != null : "fx:id=\"passwordLbl\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'passport.fxml'.";
        assert portBox != null : "fx:id=\"portBox\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'passport.fxml'.";
        assert portLbl != null : "fx:id=\"portLbl\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'passport.fxml'.";
        assert serverIPBox != null : "fx:id=\"serverIPBox\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'passport.fxml'.";
        assert serverIPLbl != null : "fx:id=\"serverIPLbl\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'passport.fxml'.";
        assert settingsButton != null : "fx:id=\"settingsButton\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'passport.fxml'.";
        assert usernameBox != null : "fx:id=\"usernameBox\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'passport.fxml'.";
        assert usernameLbl != null : "fx:id=\"usernameLbl\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'passport.fxml'.";
    }

}
```

*style.css*

```
.root {
    -fx-background-color: cornsilk;
}
```

*passport.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import java.net.URL?>
<AnchorPane fx:id="mainAnchor" opacity="1.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="408.0000999999975" styleClass="back" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="application.MainController">
    <children>
        <Label fx:id="serverIPLbl" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="28.0" prefWidth="175.0" text="Server IP">
            <font>
                <Font name="Segoe UI" size="12.0" fx:id="x1" />
            </font>
        </Label>
        <TextField fx:id="serverIPBox" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="50.0" prefWidth="175.0" />
        <Label fx:id="portLbl" font="$x1" layoutX="215.0" layoutY="28.0" prefWidth="175.0" text="Port" />
        <TextField fx:id="portBox" layoutX="215.0" layoutY="50.0" prefWidth="175.0" />
        <Label fx:id="passwordLbl" font="$x1" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="81.0" prefWidth="175.0" text="Server Password" />
        <ImageView fx:id="settingsButton" fitHeight="23.0" fitWidth="23.0" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="137.0" onMouseClicked="#settingsClicked" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
            <image>
                <Image url="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/soft-scraps/24/Gear-icon.png" />
            </image>
        </ImageView>
        <Button id="startServer" fx:id="connectButton" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="167.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#connectClicked" prefHeight="22.0" prefWidth="376.0" text="Connect" />
        <Label fx:id="usernameLbl" font="$x1" layoutX="215.0" layoutY="81.0" prefWidth="175.0" text="Username" />
        <TextField id="serverIPBox" fx:id="usernameBox" layoutX="215.0" layoutY="103.0" prefWidth="175.0" promptText="a-z A-Z 0-9 _ - chars allowed" />
        <ImageView id="favoriteButton" fx:id="favoritesButton" fitHeight="23.0" fitWidth="23.0" layoutX="55.0" layoutY="137.0" onMouseClicked="#favoritesClicked" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
            <image>
                <Image url="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/soft-scraps/24/Button-Favorite-icon.png"/>
            </image>
        </ImageView>
        <PasswordField fx:id="passwordBox" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="103.0" prefWidth="175.0" promptText="Optional" />
    </children>
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@style.css" />
    </stylesheets>
</AnchorPane>
```

*Sample program UI*

[image: sampleui]

*Sample program output*

On entering the magic work "xyzzy" in the password field and pressing connect, the program extracts the password from the field and prints it out to the console:

```
password = xyzzy
```

---

Test system used was OS X 10.9 running [Java 8b121](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html).

In future questions like this, you may want to provide a [minimal, complete, tested and readable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Such a sample isn't needed for all questions but sure would have helped with this one.

Comment: I did what you suggested but it didn't change anything

Comment: Added sample code which does not replicate the issues mentioned in your question.

Comment: I have a method in the controller class which resizes the components to work with high dpi screens. So my components have to be static because the method is static. In my Main class which has FXMLLoader, I run that method. How do I go about removing static from everything and still allow that to work? Any idea why the password field would not function while being static?

Comment: Okay so if I remove my style sheet, then the PasswordField will work. When I add it back, it breaks again!